# Modular Arithmetic Problem (Z)

Tags: modular-arithmetic, systems-of-equations, problem-solving, congruences

> Two merchants share a telephones package such that one keeps 2/7 of
> the total and the other with 5/7. The first resells them in batches of
> 51 and the second in batches of 31. When they finish, the first has 46
> telephones left and the second 19. What is the lowest initial number
> of telephones that makes this possible?

I've noticed that

- Let $x$ the initial number. The number of  telephones that  the first merchant has is $2x/7=y= 46+51\lambda\equiv 46 \mod(51)$  and
  the second $5x/7=z=19+31\mu\equiv19\mod(31)$.
- Also $x=y+z=46+51\lambda+19+31\mu=65+51\lambda+31\mu$.

  How can I continue? .. can you give any hint please?

Comment: The Chinese remainder theorem should help you out here.

Comment: @Dan What should be the system?

Comment: $2x7^{-1}\equiv46\mod{51}$ and $5x7^{-1}\equiv19\mod{31}$

Comment: yes, just multiply through by $7$ to get rid of the inverses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

lets make $7x$ the intial number of phones. (instead of x)

$51 \lambda + 46 = 2x\\
31\mu + 19 = 5x$

$2x \equiv 46\pmod {51}\\
5x \equiv 19 \pmod {31}$

The smallest $x$ that satisfies the first equation is $23$

$5(23+51\lambda) \equiv 19 \pmod {31}\\
22 + 7\lambda \equiv 19 \pmod {31}\\
7\lambda \equiv 28 \pmod {31}\\
\lambda \equiv 4\pmod {31}$

$x = 23 + 51\cdot 4 = 227\\
7x = 1589$

Comment: The first equation is wrong ? It should be $51\lambda+46=2x?$

Comment: Thanks, I have updated.

Comment: Thanks for your help